# Scala file reading and counting records

Tags: scala, hdfs

I have input file in hdfs and need to read and convert to string and store that to another file in between need to count records of that input file. I try below code and it's not working.

```
val inputStream:FSDataInputStream = fileSystem.open(dataFile)

val data = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8")

val reader: BufferedReader = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))

val count = reader.lines().count()
println( "count of file is" , count) 

reader.close()
inputStream.close()

val outputstream = fileSystem.create(newfile)
outputstream.writeBytes(data)
outputstream.close()
```

Comment: `InputStream` in Java is only readable once - when you call `IOUtils.toString(...)` on it you deplete it, that's why your `count` returns empty (if at all). You either need to do both actions together (save the contents of the file into a String + count lines), or reopen the file to count lines. I'd go with the former.

Comment: Can you give me code for  (save the contents of the file into a String + count lines)